# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' Vue Class-Bassed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

After running commend `nmp run serve` on my vue project I'm getting this two error. I am using class based vue like in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8lMkgb-8iA). This error occurred for all my vue imported files. I am a new in a vue, and I don't understand why this error happening, I have `"vue-class-component": "^7.2.6", "vue-property-decorator": "^9.0.2",` like in this tutorial and I are also importing this in my app.vue file. Author do not have this error on his video, I can find an article about this error on the internet

my main problem is this error

`Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' Vue Class-Bassed`

and

`` 11:0  error  Parsing error: Using the export keyword between a decorator and a class is not allowed. Please use `export @dec class` instead. ``

```
> hero_iii_js@0.1.0 serve C:\Users\Pawel\Unity\ArCore Portal\Heros_III_JS\hero_iii_js
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                                                 13:37:33
 error  in ./src/App.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\Pawel\Unity\ArCore Portal\Heros_III_JS\hero_iii_js\src\App.vue
   8:14  error  Replace `'ts'` with `"ts"`  prettier/prettier
  16:14  error  Delete `,`                  prettier/prettier
  17:4   error  Delete `,`                  prettier/prettier

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)
  3 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.


 @ ./src/main.js 6:0-28 10:13-16
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.43.30:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/components/boardTest.vue

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\Users\Pawel\Unity\ArCore Portal\Heros_III_JS\hero_iii_js\src\components\boardTest.vue
  11:0  error  Parsing error: Using the export keyword between a decorator and a class is not allowed. Please use `export @dec class` instead.

   5 | import Point from "./point.vue";
   6 | @Component
>  7 | export default class BoardTest extends Vue {
     | ^
   8 |   board = new Board();
   9 |   creature = new Creature();
  10 |   unitTestPoint = 1;

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 11:0-51 16:4-13
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.43.30:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./src/components/boardTest.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (10:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
PS C:\Users\Pawel\Unity\ArCore Portal\Heros_III_JS\hero_iii_js> npm run serve

> hero_iii_js@0.1.0 serve C:\Users\Pawel\Unity\ArCore Portal\Heros_III_JS\hero_iii_js
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                 13:46:14
 error  in ./src/components/boardTest.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (10:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import Point from "./point.vue";
|
> @Component
| export default class BoardTest extends Vue {
|   board = new Board();

 @ ./src/components/boardTest.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-178 1:194-197 1:199-374 1:199-374
 @ ./src/components/boardTest.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.43.30:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

point.vue

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script lang='ts'>
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class Point extends Vue {
  x;
  y;
  created(aX, aY) {
    this.x = aX;
    this.y = aY;
  }
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

boardTest.vue

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script lang='ts'>
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import Creature from "./creature.vue";
import Board from "./board.vue";
import Point from "./point.vue";

@Component
export default class BoardTest extends Vue {
  board = new Board();
  creature = new Creature();
  unitTestPoint = new Point();

  mapShouldHaveKeyAndValue() {
    this.board.add(this.unitTestPoint, this.creature);

    if (this.board.getVal(this.unitTestPoint) === undefined) {
      throw "Exception: => Creature dla tego pola zwraca undefined";
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <unitTests />
    <BoardTest />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>
import unitTests from "./components/unitTests.vue";
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import BoardTest from "./components/boardTest.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    unitTests,
    BoardTest,
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hero_iii_js",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/recommended",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
   "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The webpack rule below help me to avoid the same `Unexpected character '@'` error:

```js
// webpack.base.conf.js

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
          transpileOnly: true
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and finally, it appeared that my environment hadn't been fully set up.

> You need to configure eslint to support typescript as eslint doesn't
> support it out of the box. First, you need to install
> @typescript-eslint/parser and then @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin.

This related topic and accepted answer by [rhn-chn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17209064/rhn-chn) greatly describes which steps should you take to make it work properly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087291/2482474