# ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token :

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vuejs3

Hi everyone I am migrating my vue3 project from js to typescript, I run into this problem :

[image]

Here is my code in .vue file

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const toto = (msg: string) => {
  console.log(msg)
}
</script>
```

And here is my eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  'env': {
    'browser': true,
    'es2021': true
  },
  'extends': [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential'
  ],
  'parserOptions': {
    'ecmaVersion': 13,
    'sourceType': 'module'
  },
  'plugins': [
    'vue'
  ],
  'rules': {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
    'vue/object-curly-spacing': [2, 'always'],
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-spacing': [2, {
      'selfClosingTag': 'always'
    }],
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': [2, {
      'singleline': {
        'max': 1
      },
      'multiline': {
        'max': 1
      }
    }],
    'semi': [2, 'never']
  }
}
```

Comment: "(and I wanna die), I am a newbie to typescript". Please edit your question to remove information not inherent to the question itself

Comment: It looks like your eslint is not set up for parsing typescript. There's some docs here on how to configure it: https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/linting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to configure eslint to support typescript as eslint doesn't support it out of the box.
First, you need to install [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser) and then [@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin).
Once you have installed these, update your config as follows-

```
module.exports = {
    'env': {
        'browser': true,
        'es2021': true,
        node: true
    },
    'extends': [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:vue/vue3-essential'
    ],
    'parserOptions': {
        'ecmaVersion': 12,
        'sourceType': 'module',
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
    },
    'plugins': [
        'vue',
        '@typescript-eslint'
    ],
    'rules': {
        'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
        'vue/object-curly-spacing': [2, 'always'],
        'vue/html-closing-bracket-spacing': [2, {
            'selfClosingTag': 'always'
        }],
        'vue/max-attributes-per-line': [2, {
            'singleline': {
                'max': 1
            },
            'multiline': {
                'max': 1
            }
        }],
        'semi': [2, 'never']
    }
}
```

Comment: by doing as u said, i'm able  to lint my vue  file but not my *.ts file, I get an error like that : 
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I was using the parser option as an array, instead of a string:

```
   parserOptions: {
-    parser: ['@typescript-eslint/parser'],
+    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use both JS and TS in a project, this config helps

```
  overrides: [
     {
       files: ['*.vue'],
       parser: 'svelte-eslint-parser',
       parserOptions: {
         parser: {
           // Specify a parser for each lang.
           ts: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
           js: 'espree',
           typescript: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
         }
       }
     }
   ],
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on node v12.22.9. By upgrading to v14.21.2, I no longer had the parsing error. You can upgrade/install with the command

```
nvm install v14.21.2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).